# download kaggle notebook along with the printed logs

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, kaggle, ipynb

I ran some machine-learning notebooks on Kaggle. I created multiple versions in the same notebook. I have also put logs of the results and other important things.

Now I tried to download a specific version. It shows the logs when I view from Kaggle. I downloaded the code and opened locally and cannot see the logs. Only the code. But when I download a notebook from Google Colab I can also see the logs as well.

How do I download the logs along with the code?

This is how i downloaded the code
[image]

Comment: Using Kaggle's File > Download Notebook option does indeed include the output of each cell. How *exactly* are you downloading the code locally that this does not happen?

Comment: @esqew i updated with an image

Answer (score 1):

The `Download Code` menu option does *just* that - downloads the code, and nothing else.

To export the notebook, including the code cells and their associated outputs, open the notebook in question and select `File` → `Download Notebook`.

Comment: okay this may be stupid question. but how do i get to the view that has File menu. when i go to code and select a notebook. it opens the notebook and shows me a view only mode just like the image i posted.

Comment: If you don’t have the appropriate access to the notebook in question, you might have to select the `Copy & edit notebook` at the top of the menu you show in the screenshot of the original question first.

Comment: i will try that and see thanks

Comment: i Copy & edit notebook then it cloned the notebook. i can now see the file menu but all the logs seem to have removed in the edit view. do i also have to run again